# How can I programatically load a group?

Tags: 8, group

I have written this code to render a list of profiles (using the Profile module). It works fine.

```
// render profiles
$accounts = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::loadMultiple($uids);
$storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('profile');
if (!empty($storage)) {
  foreach ($accounts as $account) {
    $profiles[] = $storage->loadByUser($account, 'profile');
  }
  if ($profiles) {
    $content = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getViewBuilder('profile')
      ->viewMultiple($profiles, 'teaser');
  }
}
```

I have applied the same logic to rendering a list of groups (using the Group module). It fails with the error below.

```
// render groups
$groups = \Drupal\group\Entity\Group::loadMultiple($ids);
$storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('group');
if (!empty($storage)) {
  foreach ($groups as $group) {
    $test[] = $storage->loadByGroup($group, 'my_group');  // FAILS HERE
  }
  /* if ($groups) {
    $content = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getViewBuilder('group')
      ->viewMultiple($group, 'teaser');
  } */
}
```

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage::loadByGroup()

What method should I use to load a group? or how should I programatically load a group?

Thanks

Comment: `$groups = \Drupal\group\Entity\Group::loadMultiple($ids);` is what loads your Group entities. Look at its code and you will see it does the storage bits already

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding my comment as an answer:

`$groups = \Drupal\group\Entity\Group::loadMultiple($ids);` is all that is needed to load the groups based on IDs. `Group::loadMultiple()` does the storage bits already, so no need to duplicate the work.

So the full snippet would be something like:

```
<?php

$groups = \Drupal\group\Entity\Group::loadMultiple($ids);
if ($groups) {
  $content = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getViewBuilder('group')
      ->viewMultiple($group, 'teaser');
}
```

Comment: What if I just want to load a single group? `Group::load($id)` doesn't work. Is there a shortcut to not loadMultiple and then getting the first element in the array?

Comment: `Group` extends `ContentEnityBase` which defines the single load function. `Group::load($id)` *works*. Just make sure you pass the correct group id. Otherwise `$group = reset($groups);` will give you the first item

Comment: You are absolutely right. It does work. I probably messed up something else before.